# jquery how-to hide ajax loaded div on mouseleave?

Tags: jquery

I have following jquery event:

```js
$('#items').on({ mouseenter: function () {  // picshow
     itmid = $(this).attr('rel');
     var itmlink = '/scripts/iteminfo.pl?itmid='+itmid;
    $('main').append('<div id="spinner"></div>');               
    $.get(itmlink, function(data){
        var addedhtml = data;
            $('#tblitems').append('<div id="pic'+itmid+'">'+addedhtml+'</div>');
            $('#spinner').remove();
    }); 
   }, mouseleave: function () {
    $('#pic'+itmid).hide();
      }
}, '.itmpic');
```

'.itmpic' - is a div that was created dynamically.
 when mouse over that div, jquery gets 'rel' attribute value and calls script with that parameter using ajax function $.get()
The problem is that  loading takes some time ~ 1-2 seconds, and if you mouseleave from '.itmpic' when ajax div is not fully loaded yet, it will be shown on the page and there is no way to hide it.
What can i do in order to hide ajax created div even if mouseleave event was before div loaded?

Comment: The variable `itmid` is local to the mouseenter handler so in the mouseleave handler try `$(this).attr('rel')` instead of `itmid` like `$('#pic' + $(this).attr('rel')).hide();`

Comment: sorry, it was typo, itmid is global variable - i fixed it in first message.

Comment: @httpd did you try my suggestion? Feedback?

Comment: i answered above, it was a typo in my initial message.:)  the solution from salivan works for me :)

Comment: Arun P Johny thanks, that also useful comment,  by the way, is it the best way for passing variables from mouseenter: function() -> mouseleave: function () ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple logic change:

1) Create container div before ajax call.

2) than use ajax to populate div with content.

3) On mouseleave hide container div.

```
$('#items').on({ mouseenter: function () {  // picshow
    var itmid = $(this).attr('rel'),
        itmlink = '/scripts/iteminfo.pl?itmid='+itmid;
    $('main').append('<div id="spinner"></div>');
    $('#tblitems').append('<div id="pic'+itmid+'"></div>');               
    $.get(itmlink, function(data){
        var addedhtml = data;
            $('#pic'+itmid).html(addedhtml);
            $('#spinner').remove();
    }); 
   }, mouseleave: function () {
    $('#pic'+itmid).hide();
      }
}, '.itmpic');
```

Thus avoiding all your troubles in a simple way. I cannot test this anywhere, but it should work.

Comment: @httpd great, glad to have helped! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could set a variable in the mouseleave handler which you then check in the ajax reponse. If the variable is set, then you hide the new element. You would also have to clear the variable in the mouseenter functon as well.